# Jackson xml Unrecognized Property Exception after karate 1.2.0 upgrade

Tags: java, karate, bdd, jackson-databind, web-api-testing

I have a existing test for a endpoint which was working fine with Karate 1.1.0 but after recent update to karate 1.2.0 it stopped working due to Jackson xml uncognised property exception
test endpoint which accepts request body in terms of multipart/form-data. When I try to post data to endpoint with request body and a document as multipart fields which was working fine if I use karate core version as 1.1.0 but when I update to 1.2.0 it's not working and I'm hitting error

> Exception occurred in Restapi class of ReponseEntity method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UncognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "read"

My feature file:

```
Given url basetesturl + 'test1/test'
And header Content-Type ='multipart/form-data'
And header Authorization = "Bearer"+ Oathtoken
And multipart field documents= {read:'classpath:testdoc.pdf', filename:'testdoc.pdf'content:'application/pdf'
 And multipart field Data= {read:'classpath:testreqpl.json', filename:'testreqpl.json'content:'multipart/form-data' 
And method POST
Then status 200
```

Comment: most likely a library conflict not related to karate. the ONLY way to get help is to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - also note that we released 6 RC versions precisely so that such problems can be identified, so now you may have to wait or use the old version

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you try the option to use the `all` classifier:

https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.2.0-Upgrade-Guide

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
  <artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
  <version>${karate.version}</version>
  <classifier>all</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Let me try this option and confirm whether it works, I've also submitted this as an issue in the karate GitHub page

Comment: I have added the Gradle equivalent of classifier as given below  testCompile "com.karate:karate-junit5:1.2.0:all"  but it's not working and keep hitting the same error as mentioned in the question jackson xml Unrecognized field "read"

Comment: @hamsaraj I have nothing to add to my comments above